# set a delegate for UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

How do I set a delegate for my `UIWebView` to use `webViewDidFinishLoad`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the interface file indicate that you're interested:

```
@interface SomethingController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
```

Then in your implementation you'll add that delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    // Do whatever you want here

}
```

Obviously *SomethingController* should be your actual controller, and *UIViewController* is whatever you're actually implementing.

This, by the way, is basically how you implement any delegate.

**Edit**

In a window-based app, assuming your UIWebView is in your app delegate, you just add it to the list of delegates, separated by commas, like this:

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
```

You'll include your **webViewDidFinishLoad** in the app delegate's implementation.

**Edit 2**

Finally, you'll need to connect your UIWebView to your controller. It's common to do this in the  `viewDidLoad` method of a UIViewController, with a line like this:

```
self.yourWebView.delegate = self;
```

This tells the UIWebView where it should send messages.

Comment: what if i do not have a controller because i am using the windows application template. which only give me two files.. .h and .m.

Sorry, i am very new to this..Thanks :)

Comment: Wherever your web view is, that's where you'll listen for the delegate. I'll edit my answer where formatting is better.

Comment: hmmm ok thanks dude, i decided to use view-based app instead... can i ask you one more question? actually my purpose is i want to use the delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad  to load finish a webpage first before running some other codes. So where should i put my loading of webpage codes? inside loadView?

Comment: Sure, you can load the UIWebView in your view controller's ViewDidLoad, and then put the code you want to run after the webview has loaded in the webViewDidFinishLoad. (If this answered your question, check the checkmark next to the answer, not this comment.)

Answer (score 6):

Follow the screen shot below

[image]

after connecting `inYourViewController.h`

```
@interface inYourViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

now you are ready to implement the delegate methods in `inYourViewController.m` file.

or

you can do the same thing from code.

After connecting the webView with view controller via `IBOutlet`,In `inYourViewController.m` file's `viewDidLoad` Method write

```
self.yourWebView.delegate=self
```

In `inYourViewController.h`

```
@interface inYourViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Now you are ready to implement the delegate method of webView.Thanks