# How do i convert UIWebView to bitmap

Tags: ios, uiwebview, bitmap

Hi everybody i'm stuck with trying to convert my UIWebView, in which i'm currently displaying a ppt file, to a bitmap image.

I have this code:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 708)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

NSLog(@"Ouverture du contexte image");
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webView.bounds.size);
[webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The webview is actually well displayed but I didn't manage to create it's render to an image,
If anybody knows where is the issue ;)
Thankss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your screenshot-taking code — you're just using it prematurely.

`[webView loadRequest:request];` initiates an asynchronous client request. That means you're taking a screenshot of `webView` before it even loads its contents.

Move your screenshot-taking code to `UIWebViewDelegate`'s method `webViewDidFinishLoad:`. Of course you're going to have to assign a `delegate` to your `webView` to achieve this.

Comment: But i don't really understand, because my powerpoint file is displayed correctly and the image is also created but all in white with no content :s
What you just said about `[webView loadRequest:request];` isn't related to the conversion to image i guess, it is just use to display the powerpoint isn't it ?
But i'm going to have a look on what you said thanks ;)

Comment: You're welcome! When you call `loadRequest:` webView starts loading it's contents. But you are trying to make a screenshot immediatly - that's why you're getting blank screenshot. There's a delay between calling `loadRequest:` and webView actually being populated. You should wait until contents is loaded. That is why screenshot-taking code should be moved to `webViewDidFinishLoad:`

Comment: ahhhh ok! :)
But do i have to implement another class for the delegate? I'm in a split view template and this function is called from the detail view controller (so a uiviewcontroller). I guess the didfinishlaunching method in the controller can't solve my problem?

Comment: Delegate can be any object - if your webView is a subview of some UIViewController it would be best to make that UIViewController a delegate of webView. This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342006/set-a-delegate-for-uiwebview