# UIWebViewDelegate methods not getting called

Tags: ios, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to use UIWebViewDelegate methods. I set its delegate to self but still not working

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"Load view");    
}   

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"Finish View");   
}


-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error in loading: %@", [error description]);
}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: none of these methods get called... not giving error as well @jbkkd

Comment: @WasimAhmad You Set Delegate in Xib File?

Comment: Where do you set `delegate` to `self`? Please show that as well, if it's in code.

Comment: i set the delegate in viewcontroller.m file.. @iOSDeveloper

Comment: @WasimAhmad also Connect WebView Delegate to Your File Owner if you Use WebView Controller in Xib file.and Pest Your Some Code for Your WebView.

Comment: @RileyAvron  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    
        self.viewWeb.delegate = self;
        NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.wherewomenmeet.org";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest     requestWithURL:url];
        [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
     }

Comment: i don't use any xib file rather i use .storyboard.. @iOSDeveloper

Comment: @WasimAhmad Connect Your Webview Delgate to your View Controller in StoryBoard and Also You Set in You .h file <UIWebViewDelegate>?

Comment: i have added to .h file, but how can i connect web view delegate to storyboard @iOSDeveloper

Comment: @WasimAhmad Why Not When You Click On Your WebView in StoryBoard and Show in Connection Inspector it Shows Delegate that Connect it to Your View Controller. also Show this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342006/set-a-delegate-for-uiwebview

Comment: @WasimAhmad try following instructions from this
article:
http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/d/d1/UIWebview_example_code.txt
there is the comment section "In the .xib file", go to your storyboard, click on your View and follow the instructions described in that comment. That should help.

Comment: @WasimAhmad Can you Get Solution?

Comment: i am trying it, and letting you know then.. thanks @iOSDeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not write anything in `viewDidLoad`. Try putting webview related code `viewDidAppear` or any custom method. Cross check if your webview is connected properly in storyboard.

Comment: its now working..!! i connect delegate to my viewcontroller. what i was doing wrong is, i was calling uiwebviewdelegate methods in myappdelegate.m file, now i added these methods in viewload (); . it worked for me thanks every one for help.

Comment: gr8.. :) Accept the answer it was helpful to you.